# Type checking for mutually-referencing classes

Tags: python

Sorry if this turns out to be a noob question, but I tried google and it didn't help. Say I have two classes, A and B. I want A to take an instance of B as argument. Similarly, I want B to take an instance of A. If I define my classes in different modules and want my classes to be type checked, I would have to import B to the module that contains A and vice-versa, which would bring me to a circle import. How should I go about this? Is there a way to just declare the existence of these classes before actually defining them, so I can reference them in the **init** function once I do?

I tried defining all the classes inside the same module, which works, but this defeats the purpose of project organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, its best to avoid the circular nature altogether. One way to do this is use an abstract baseclass for the important functionality, or you can use Protocols for this purpose as well.

Say we have these two classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a_property = "a"

    def action(self, b: B) -> None:
        print(b.b_property)


class B:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.b_property = "b"

    def action(self, a: A) -> None:
        print(a.a_property)
```

This has an obvious cycle. If we abstract out the important components to a protocol, then we can avoid the cycle:

```
from typing import Protocol


class AProtocol(Protocol):
    a_property: str


class BProtocol(Protocol):
    b_property: str


class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a_property = "a"

    def action(self, b: BProtocol) -> None:
        print(b.b_property)


class B:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.b_property = "b"

    def action(self, a: AProtocol) -> None:
        print(a.a_property)
```

Answer (score 1):

To break the forward reference in a *single* file, you can either quote the name or use [`__future__.annotations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html).

```
def example(a: 'A'):
    ...

class A:
    pass
```

or

```
from __future__ import annotations

def example(a: A):
    ...

class A:
    pass
```

To break the cycle between two *different* modules, you can use [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING). This is a Boolean that's always false when Python runs. But it's true when a type-checker is analyzing your code. Type-checkers have no problem with circular module imports, so if the cycle only exists inside a `TYPE_CHECKING` block, the runtime will never notice.

```
# example.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from a import A

def example(a: A):
    ...

# a.py
class A:
    pass
```

When type-checking, the `if TYPE_CHECKING` block is true, and the module gets imported. But at runtime, the class `A` isn't needed and is never even brought into scope.

Note that you still need to either quote the type or use `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your file, for you'll still have the issue of the name not existing at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have `main1.py` and `main2.py` modules with `class A` and `class B` respectively.

main1.py

```py
from main2 import Main2
class Main1:
   def method(self, main: Main2):
      ...
```

In "main2.py" you can't import `Main1` directly, so you can use this pattern

main2.py

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
   from main1 import Main1

class Main2:
   def method(self, main: "Main1"):
      ...
```

Here, we use TYPE CHECKING to ensure that a circular import error does not occur during normal execution.